# Preventing hang with a timeout?

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, timeout

I've made a bot that uses the Selenium Webdriver Module to navigate a website. Unfortunately I've noticed that the script will sometime stop when it tries to click a button. The code is simple. I try to click the button, if I can't we wait a second and try again. It works, but at seemingly random times (sometimes after 10 minutes, sometimes after several hours) it just stops after clicking the button.

```
while 1:
    try:
        #Try to click the button
        confirmButton = driver.find_element_by_name("confirm")
        confirmButton.click()
    #If we can't, wait a second and try again
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
```

I've been thinking about creating some way to detect this, thus being able to timeout the current attempt to click, but I can't seem to figure out how. The script of single threaded and I can't use the simple datetime technique, as it would never run that check, since it's still waiting for the button to have finished being clicked on.

Edit: Someone asked me how I knew it was hanging and not just retrying indefinitely. I did a test where I printed a number for each line that was executed and when I the hang occurred it would not execute any of he lines below `confirmButton.click()`. I think that is proof that it's hanging and not retrying indefinitely. Or maybe not?

Comment: You're not showing the whole code that corresponds with your description of what the script does. There's no trying again in the code you show. Please edit the code so that it corresponds to what you describe. Also, please indicate how you know that it is *hanging* and not just *retrying indefinitely*.

Comment: Alright, I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with a timeout: launch a function in a separate thread and stops after a certain time limit if the function is not finished.

Here is the example

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def threaded_function():
    confirmButton = driver.find_element_by_name("confirm")
    confirmButton.click()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = Thread(target = threaded_function)
    thread.start()
    thread.join(1)# this means the thread stops after 1 second, even if it is not finished yet
    print ("thread finished...exiting")
```

Hope that helps, and tell me if it does not solve the prob.

Comment: I've heard talk about signal not working on windows and when I test it I get this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIGALRM'. Do you know of a way to do it on windows?

Comment: fixed it and simplified the code so that it is simple to understand now